# RSpec test if a function was called

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am new to RSpec and am diving into the deep end. I was hoping to test some trivial functions simply to get familiar with the RSpec DSL. So, to the point: How would I test the following snippit using RSpec's 3.1.7 syntax? More specifically, how do I test if a function is called?

---

### Code:

```
manipulate_loc(loc, op, n)
    x = loc.x.send(op, n)
    y = loc.y.send(op, n)
    yield x, y
end

def scale_up(loc, n)
    manipulate_loc(loc, :*, n)
end
```

### Test:

```
it 'can scale up Locations' do
    expect(scale_up(subject,2)).to receive(:manipulate_loc).with(subject, 2)
end
```

---

I understand this is a weird example because I am passing blocks around, but what would ruby be without blocks!

Comment: Not related to testing, but where are you passing blocks around? `manipulate_loc(loc, :+, n)` does not send a block, so `yield` should fail in this code.

Comment: @Amadan you're right, manipulate_loc will yield a block, not pass it... My grasp on Ruby blocks is still fuzzy, but it doesn't fail. It can be used like so: manipulate_loc(loc, :+, n){|x,y| ...} and everything works fine. I am trying to use blocks to manipulate Ruby objects, in this case Locations that have x and y coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test if a method is called, you mock the method (create a fake method) that will imitate the method whose calling you are testing. In Ruby, all functions are methods on *something*, even if that is the main object (`self` in this context). If you are actually testing a method on some class (as you should; it is very bad for maintainability of Ruby code to define methods on main), replace `self` with `Foo.new` or similar.

It is hard to create a test case when you don't give us what the functions should do, and then write them incorrectly, so I'll fix them up a bit, and you can adapt them later to your use case:

```
def manipulate_loc(loc, op, n)
    x = loc.x.send(op, n)
    y = loc.y.send(op, n)
    [x, y]
end

def scale_up(loc, n)
    manipulate_loc(loc, :*, n)
end


it 'can scale up Locations' do
  expect(self).to receive(:manipulate_loc).with(subject, :*, 2).and_return([4, 10])
  expect(scale_up(subject, 2)).to equal([4, 10])
end
```

The `expect... to receive... with... and_return...` is making a fake method that behaves in the specified way and replacing your method with it. Test passes if the fake method is called. (There is a further expectation that the method you are calling to call your mocked method is actually doing the right thing.)

Comment: Thank you for this @Amadan, I will give it a shot when I have some more free time. The goal, as I stated in your other comment above, is to easily mutate class attributes on the fly (using blocks and procs). It is a Gosu project in which I am modeling "bugs" (Locations) that move around a screen randomly.

Comment: I want to limit the use of passing around arrays and hashes as much as possible in the hopes of getting a better grasp on Ruby blocks.